# Access Query Criteria from form

Tags: ms-access

This should be fairly simple but I am going round the houses !

Using VBA how can I change the criteria of a numerical field in a query with multiple options.

e.g. if I was editing the query I would just type in "1 or 2 or 3"

The Criteria changes at different times of the day, so sometimes it may be "3 or 4" e.t.c.

I am using Office 365.

Any help would be appreciated.....

Comment: Hi Simon! Could you elaborate a bit? Are you trying to create a form that changes depending on time of day? Should the query change automatically depending on the time of day? Which applications are you using, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use the *IN* operator and rebuild your SQL when the filter changes:

```
Select * From YourTable Where ID In (1,2,3)

Select * From YourTable Where ID In (3,4)
```